# Running shell_exec with flock in php

Tags: php, shell-exec, flock

I have a code that tries to run a Shell script with the flock function, but it seems to not run when the shell script is under flock. The code is as follows:

```
$fp = fopen("ssh_git.sh", "a+");

if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)){
        $shell_output = shell_exec("/path/to/script/ssh_git.sh");

        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

} else
{
        echo "Error! File is in use by another user!<br>";
}
fclose ($fp);
```

It works when I move the `shell_exec()` outside of the `flock()`..

Am I doing it wrong? I tried running fopen with r+,x+,a+.. but it still doesn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated!